# Python documentation in wiki-like environment (with some autodoc features)

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have investigated, and have high hopes for, sphinx.

However, it doesn't do everything I want in a documentation framework.  Here's what I'm looking for:

- A wiki-like (ie, web-editable) environment with revision tracking
- Support for autodoc (ie importing of docstrings, etc.)
- (ideally) a connector to version management so that the code can be browsed from earlier revisions

Does any such thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

GitHub's [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum) which is a "A simple, Git-powered wiki with a sweet API and local frontend" could be a possible solution. It supports reStructured Text, which as you probably know, is the same markup used by Sphinx.

Comment: I looked at Gollum, but it doesn't appear to import docstrings from python, am I right?  Or did I miss somethign?

Comment: I don't know, but I've been considering using Gollum myself lately, which is why I suggested it. I imagined that using Sphinx first to generate your RST, would then put you into a position to then store those pages in Gollum?  I haven't gotten there yet myself but that's what I intend to try.  Also, have you tried readthedocs.org?

Comment: Yep, readthedocs.org is awesome.  However, it's not exactly what I have described above.